# Shifting Timezones in Datetime format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have an array of Datetime timestamps in MATLAB, all in UTC. I would like to convert them all to another timezone (Europe/Madrid). Is there a simple function to do it?

(My first post here, do let me know if I did something wrong!)

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this link? http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specify-time-zones.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Doh! You are right :D Thanks!